# Can you replace macros in a specific order?

Tags: c++, macros, include

I am trying to embed a file as a string in a C++ file.

Some have suggested adding `R(` and `)` to the beginning and end of the file. That way

```
string str = #include "my_file";
```

Becomes a well-formed statement.

I don’t quite like having to manually append the `R(` and `)`, so I am thinking I can instead make a macro sort of like this:

```
MACRO1 // resolves to R(
#include "MyFile"
MACRO2 // resolves to )
```

This requires that the #include is replaced before or at the same time as the other 2 macros, else the string would become literally `#include "MyFile"`.

Is there a way to cntrol when the macros get replaced?

Comment: `#include` and other directives only work in specific contexts. Not like this. You may need a code generator. You can't just dump in arbitrary text. Remember, in C++ *strings need escaping* and `#include` just drops junk in as-is.

Comment: Wow! I'm really curious about the use case and/or the context that requires such a thing.

Comment: @kebs There's a bunch of use cases. One I had once was to add the generated hash arrays for various CRC checksum algos. There were others as well, though it's not possible to solve that using the preprocessors to create string literals of any kind.

Comment: @kebs I am embedding shader source code and images / data into my executable to reduce startup times.

Comment: "*I am trying to embed a file as a string in a C++ file*" - why? How are you planning on using the string at runtime? Which platform(s) are you targeting? On Windows, for instance, using `.rc`/`.res` files to link binary resources into the final executable is generally a better option, especially when "*embedding ... images / data*".

Comment: There is a strict subset of minimum resources that are needed for the program to give meaningful output. This reduced subset is to be embedded in the executable.

This specific question was about the shaders, which are better stored as a string rather than as a linked object file.

Comment: why dont you put the `R(` and `)` in `myfile` ?

Comment: You could write your own pre-pre-processor, say based in Python, which looks for (say) `##include "MyFile"` (note the two `##`) and plops the contents of the file at that spot.  Then you wouldn't need the `MACRO1` and `MACRO2`, you could just `char const* shader = R"funsies(` and `)funsies";`

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818

That requires doing it for every file and requires taking it out if the file is loaded through another mechanism, say by reading it from disk. In general it's just more likely to cause headaches in the future.

Comment: @Eljay Then I have to modify my build system to ignore the original file and use the modified file instead, which makes it more complex.

I found a library that seems to do the trick:

https://github.com/graphitemaster/incbin/

Testing it out

Comment: @Makogan i dont really understand what you say, but consider that once you started such including you can also wrap myfile into myotherfile which contains nothing but `R(  #include "myfile"  )`

Comment: [`std::embded` proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1040r0.html)